# Send notification to apps using fcm and java with data

Tags: java, android, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

Can Firebase cloud messaging send notifications to apps with data on it? And when notification clicked, it will open new activity and display those data. I have been try to search on internet, but the cannot find one.

Comment: Thank you, i'll try it, but, if those datas retrieve from firebase realtime database too, should i get from api? Or in java??

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can send data with notification and can be received in device [Receiving data from FCM push notification](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive)

Comment: So, if those datas retrieve from firebase realtime database too, should i get it from api? Or in java ?

Comment: Anyway, thank youu so much for your suggestion:)